# How to solve a Linear System of Equations in Python When the Coefficients are Unknown (but still real numbers)

Tags: python, linear-algebra, equation, solver, equation-solving

Im not a programer so go easy on me please ! I have a system of 4 linear equations and 4 unknowns, which I think I could use python to solve relatively easily. However my equations not of the form " 5x+2y+z-w=0 " instead I have algebraic constants c_i which I dont know the explicit numerical value of, for example " c_1 x + c_2 y + c_3 z+ c_4w=c_5 " would be one my four equations. So does a solver exist which gives answers for x,y,z,w in terms of the c_i ?

Comment: I will suggest you to look at `sympy` and `numpy`. Even if you are having coefficient in list the logic will remain the same.

Comment: @Pygirl Oh really? Ill check it out then thanks.

Comment: look at this: https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/sympy-expressions-and-equations.html

Comment: You want to find the c_i values as a function of x,y,z?

Comment: I want to find x,y,z,w as functions of c_i. @Filipe

Comment: So you may check this https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html.

Comment: @Filipe but there all the c_i are known numerical values e.g 3 , for me I don't know them they are just some constants.

Comment: Surprised this isn't easier to do...

Comment: It seems impossible to me. I mean, if all your coefficients are variables, you have more variables than equations, so the system can not be determined.

Comment: They are fixed constants...

Comment: not variables, im just asking python to rearrange a system of equations. gaussian elimination. Get some solution like x= c_1+c_2 , y = c_2+3c_3 , z = c_4 , w = c_1+4c_4

Comment: the link @Pygirl seems pretty good, cheers.

Comment: In fact that works perfectly super easy Thanks !!!

Comment: Ok, got it. numpy wont do that. You need to find something on sympy, since this is symbolic computation. If you dont really need python just solve the problem, you should try something on wolfram, maybe this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=c7ed0940269be9cb7ee63dbda138e6e4

Comment: @Filipe sympy working just fine thanks :) cheers dude !

Comment: I am glad I was able to help :)

Comment: Since you are new here i will quickly point this out: After some time you are able to confirm a solution. Since we spend quite a bit of time solving other peoples problems we'd appreciate that recognition for our work.

Comment: Dude I am serious about that. I spent two hours on this :)

Comment: @PixelRayn I had found a solution from Pygirls link already. But thanks anywho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy has a function for this exact problem: `numpy.linalg.solve`

To construct the  matrix we first need to digest the string turning it into an array of coefficients and solutions.

## Finding Numbers

First we need to write a function that takes a string like "c_1 3" and returns the number 3.0. Depending on the format you want in your input string you can either iterate over all chars in this array and stop when you find a non-digit character, or you can simply split on the space and parse the second string. Here are both solutions:

```
def find_number(sub_expr):

    """
    Finds the number from the format
    number*string or numberstring.

    Example:
    3x -> 3
    4*x -> 4
    """

    num_str = str()

    for char in sub_expr:
        if char.isdigit():
            num_str += char
        else:
            break

    return float(num_str)
```

or the simpler solution

```
def find_number(sub_expr):
    """
    Returns the number from the format "string number"
    """
    return float(sub_expr.split()[1])
```

> Note: See edits

## Get matrices

Now we can use that to split each expression into two parts: The solution and the equation by the "=". The equation is then split into sub_expressions by the "+" This way we would end turn the string "3x+4y = 3" into

```
sub_expressions = ["3x", "4y"]
solution_string = "3"
```

Each sub expression then needs to be fed into our `find_numbers` function. The End result can be appended to the coefficient and solution matrices:

```
def get_matrices(expressions):

    """
    Returns coefficient_matrix and solutions from array of string-expressions.
    """

    coefficient_matrix = list()
    solutions = list()

    last_len = -1

    for expression in expressions:

        # Note: In this solution all coefficients must be explicitely noted and must always be in the same order.
        # Could be solved with dicts but is probably overengineered.

        if not "=" in expression:
            print(f"Invalid expression {expression}. Missing \"=\"")
            return False

        try:
            c_string, s_string = expression.split("=")

            c_strings = c_string.split("+")
            solutions.append(float(s_string))

            current_len = len(c_strings)

            if last_len != -1 and current_len != last_len:
                print(f"The expression {expression} has a mismatching number of coefficients")
                return False

            last_len = current_len

            coefficients = list()

            for c_string in c_strings:
                coefficients.append(find_number(c_string))

            coefficient_matrix.append(coefficients)


        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An unexpected Runtime Error occured at {coefficient}")
            print(e)
            exit()

    return coefficient_matrix, solutions
```

Now let's write a simple main function to test this code:

```
# This is not the code you want to copy-paste
# Look further down.
from sys import argv as args

def main():
    expressions = args[1:]

    matrix, solutions = get_matrices(expressions)

    for row in matrix:
        print(row)

    print("")
    print(solutions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Let's run the program in the console!

```
user:$ python3 solve.py 2x+3y=4 3x+3y=2
[2.0, 3.0]
[3.0, 3.0]

[4.0, 2.0]
```

You can see that the program identified all our numbers correctly

> AGAIN: use the find_number function appropriate for your format

## Put The Pieces Together

These Matrices now just need to be pumped directly into the numpy function:

```
# This is the main you want
from sys import argv as args
from numpy.linalg import solve as solve_linalg

def main():
    expressions = args[1:]

    matrix, solutions = get_matrices(expressions)

    coefficients = solve_linalg(matrix, solutions)

    print(coefficients)

# This bit needs to be at the very bottom of your code to load all functions first.
# You could just paste the main-code here, but this is considered best-practice
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now let's test that:

```
$ python3 solve.py x*2+y*4+z*0=20 x*1+y*1+z*-1=3 x*2+y*2+z*-3=3
[2. 4. 3.]
```

As you can see the program now solves the functions for us.

Out of curiosity: Math homework? This feels like math homework.

Edit: Had a typo "c_string" instead of "c_strings" worked out in all tests out of pure and utter luck.

Edit 2: Upon further inspection I would reccomend to split the sub-expressions by a "*":

```
def find_number(sub_expr):
    """
    Returns the number from the format "string number"
    """
    return float(sub_expr.split("*")[1])
```

This results in fairly readable input strings